# manipulating list of strings in python

Tags: python

How can I obtain the expected result below?

```
data = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
```

Expected result is:

```
 [abc, def, ghi]
```

My attempt is:

```
ans = [', '.join([''.join(i) for i in data])]
print ans 
['abc, def, ghi']
```

Comment: That looks fine what is the problem?

Comment: Maybe `"[" + ", ".join(data) + "]"` ?

Comment: Do you mean the output you expect is `"[abc, def, ghi]"`? You understand what the quote marks and brackets actually *mean*, yes?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
>>> ans = '[' + ', '.join([''.join(i) for i in data]) + ']'
>>> ans
'[abc, def, ghi]'
>>>
```

Comment: @alps  Just want to know if this is a correct answer, so i can improve my answer.

Comment: this does not match your expected output, what do you actually want as output?

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the list into a string, then use `replace` to remove the quotation marks.

```
data = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
ans = str(data).replace('\'', '')
print(ans)
```

Output:

```
[abc, def, ghi]
```

Simples!